# How to filter Django GeopositionField based on longitude or latitude

Tags: python, django, django-geoposition

I have a geoposition field that contains lat,long value of a point.

```
>> object.location
>>11.23,21.23

>>object.location.latitude
 >> 11.23
```

I have tried

```
queryset.filter(location__latitude__lte=20.00)
```

but its not working.

Answer (score 0):

```
from geoposition.fields import Geoposition

n = Geoposition(11.23, 21.23)
queryset.filter(location=n)
```

Comment: could you provide a bit more detail to the answer and explain why it works?